# Object containing arrays - is there a simpler way to write this common pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, javascript-objects

Often times I want to create a javascript object and insert items into an array at a certain index. I find myself writing this pattern a lot:

```
var obj = {}
for (let item of list) {
    if (obj[condition] == undefined) {
        obj[condition] = [item];
    } else {
        obj[condition].push(item);
    }
}
```

I just find it frustrating to be constantly checking for undefined. Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: Thank to Nick for helping me find a solution I like

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var obj = {}
for (let item in list) {
    obj[item%2] = [...obj[item%2] || [], item]
}

console.log(obj)
```

And the functional method:

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var obj = list.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item%2] = [...acc[item%2] || [], item]
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to like using `reduce` for these kinds of cases. You still end up having to do a check to see if the array exists yet, but you might be able to condense the logic like in the following code.

```js
const list = [{
  type: "fruit",
  item: "apple"
}, {
  type: "veggie",
  item: "corn"
}, {
  type: "fruit",
  item: "banana"
}];

const obj = list.reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc[el.type] = [...acc[el.type] || [], el.item];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. I used your reduce internal function and I'll keep your reduce preference in mind. I need to use it more. Edited my post for my solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array spread operator to simplify the operation. 
)`obj[condition] = obj[condition]? [...obj[condition], item] : [item];`